# How to define my own data to insert DB in YCSB?

Tags: mongodb, benchmarking, ycsb

I'm using YCSB to benchmark my MongoDB cluster. As I read on  https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Running-a-Workload

> For CoreWorkload, the YCSB Client will assume that there is a "table" called "usertable" with a flexible schema: columns can be added at runtime as desired.

then when I executed load workload, YCSB client inserted to MongDB data like:
[MongoDB record data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A7cx.png)

As my purpose, I want to test with real data.

How can I modify/create my own data for YCSB client can use it to insert in load phase?

Thanks,